# Most efficient way to play sound (many play button in one page)

Tags: html, flash, audio, embed

I have a page where the user can click a button to play word pronunciation,

you can take a loot at http://japaneseclass.jp/note/open/351

Right now, the page uses flash player, and it is really heavy to load about 100 flash sound button on a single page.

I have already tried other flash player such as 1bit player, and they are all the same (heavy)

What are some other alternatives?

I tried to use embed, and it is also heavy.
What I have in mind is to use img button and use javascript to play it, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create one flash audio player that sits somewhere on the page unseen, and make your buttons call it using ExternalInterface, passing a reference to the mp3 you want to play.  That way the actual media player is very small, and it loads in the audio tracks on demand.